# log.Info and log.Verbose - where can I see the output in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Following is some code extracted from my Azure Function which is being called from a Logic App:

```
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose($"Function Run Called");
    var jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    log.Info($"jsonContent var assigned {jsonContent}");
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent.ToString());
    log.Verbose($"data var assigned");
    log.Verbose($"JsonContent: {data.FileContent}!"); 
    bool result = true;
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {
        result = $"Hello {result}!"
    });    
}
```

Once executed, I can see the function executed successfully without any errors, but I am unable to see what "log.Verbose" has printed. I have also tried log.Info but I don't see any output.

Any idea from where I can check the output of log.Info and log.Verbose?

Comment: You should be able to see the logs in the portal log streaming window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your scenario you're not actually using our Functions portal for the invocations, then to see the logs, you can go to the **"Monitor" page** for your function. From the invocation log you can select individual functions and see their output under the invocation details section.

When running functions from our Functions portal, you'll see the logs in the **log stream window**. Note that the default TraceLevel configured for a Function app is **Info**. So you won't see **Verbose** logs. You can configure the TraceLevel in your `host.json` file by setting the `tracing.consoleLevel` property. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json) for more information.